# Is there a way to get the style attributes of a div?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a div which I set the styling from overflow:auto to display:none depending on which buttons are pressed. Is there a way to retrieve which current styling it has and return that value as a string or something in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give the div element the runat="server" tag, and access it in codebehind (it is a HtmlGenericControl.

You can get/set the Style property of the div control via ".Style.Value".

```
<div id="Foo" runat="server"></div>
```

CodeBehind example:

```
string myStyle = Foo.Style.Value;
Foo.Style.Value = "padding: 0px;";
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was looking to do this somewhere in myDiv.Attributes since that's where I was adding and deleting styles. But I guess that was the wrong path.